# Duplicate checker not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to allow users to upload youtube video URLs to a database, but want to check if the URL has already been taken. When the form has been filled out (checked by an if statement), it continues on to upload the files but first checks with a function(vid) if its already been uploaded. When I try the code, I get an error:

> mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/content/95/8201295/html/dialog/youtube-up.php on line 76
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/content/95/8201295/html/dialog/youtube-up.php on line 78
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/content/95/8201295/html/dialog/youtube-up.php on line 79
> Video SUbmited

Can someone help, here is my code. Thanks for any help i get.

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/Main.php'); 

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_Main, $Main);
$query_youtube = "SELECT video_id FROM youtube";
$youtube = mysql_query($query_youtube) or die(mysql_error());
$row_youtube = mysql_fetch_assoc($youtube);
$totalRows_youtube = mysql_num_rows($youtube);

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
function vid ($vid) {
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM youtube WHERE video_id = '".$vid."'";
$result = mysql_query($SQL, $Main);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows > 0) {
$errorMessage = "Video already taken";
echo($errorMessage);
return false;
} 
else {
    echo('Video SUbmited');
    return true;
}
    }
    $pieces = explode("=", $_POST['url']);
    $Ndone = $pieces[1];
    $pieces = explode("&", $Ndone);
    $done = $pieces[0];
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "youtube")) {
    if(vid($done)) {
         $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO youtube (video_id) VALUES (%s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($done, "text"));

        $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $Main) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="../SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.text_box {
    text
    font-size: 9px;
    color: #000;
    }
</style>
<body>
 
  <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="youtube" height="100px" method="POST" id="youtube">
    <span id="url">
    <input type="text" class="text_box" value="type in url of video " name="url" id="url2" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
    </input>
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="youtube" />
    </p>
    </input>
  </form>
  <?php ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("url", "url", {validateOn:["blur"]});
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($youtube);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided doesn't contain the error. For some reason that we don't know, `mysql_connect` fails, thus causing all your errors. Basically, the problem lies in the $database_Main variable, which is not a correct MySQL result resource, as stated by the error message.

You should most likely read more about debugging, because your question shows you have great lack of knowledge in this domain.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm new to php, for the most part i've used c and c++. Thanks again.